# Typescript generic arguments not resolved correclty

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

consider this, a generic class

```
export class Query<TResult> {
}
```

A extending class of that type

```
export class ListSomeNumbersQuery extends Query<number[]> {
    constructor() {
        super();           
    }
}
```

A visitor class

```
class CqsClient {
    executeQuery<TResult>(query: Query<TResult>): TResult {
        //TODO: implement
    }
}
```

usage

```
var result = client.executeQuery(new ListSomeNumbersQuery());
```

Visual Studio IDE does not understand that result is a number array. Whats wrong?

edit: Really funny choice by Anders Hejlsberg, Typescript is a type erasure language so generics are only compile time syntax sugar. But adding a private property does work

```
export class Query<TResult> {
    private _dummy: TResult;
}
```

Comment: Does the problem go away if you add properties to `Query`?  If it's [empty you might have problems](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-doesnt-type-inference-work-on-this-interface-interface-foot---)

Comment: More specifically add a property property of type `TResult` or use `TResult` in any way in the class. Unused generics don't count for much. With this it will work :`export class Query<TResult> {
    private __justForTs!: TResult;
}`

Comment: It's just a markup abstract base class

Comment: It's use to mark what the backend service will return it used from the none abstract classes as you can see in my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens because you don't use your type variable `TResult` in your Query class.

From [Docs](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-doesnt-type-inference-work-on-this-interface-interface-foot---):

> When inferring the type of T in the function call, we try to find members of type T on the x argument to figure out what T should be. Because there are no members which use T, there is nothing to infer from, so we return {}.

If you change it to

```
export class Query<TResult> {
  private result: TResult;
}
```

it will correctly identify the result as a `number[]` instead of `{}`

Comment: Change it to private property (since its not used) and I will mark as answer